# Longsleeve shirt, long sleeve shirt, or long-sleeved shirt?

Tags: difference, terminology

Hello: Is it [longsleeve](https://www.aritzia.com/intl/en/product/contour-longsleeve-bodysuit/73936.html?dwvar_73936_color=1275) shirt? [long sleeve](https://www.columbia.com/mens-long-sleeve-shirts/) shirt? Or [long-sleeved](https://m2.hm.com/m/en_us/productpage.0596400007.html) shirt? It's so confusing.

Answer (score 1):

I agree, it is confusing. It appears that the proper term is "long sleeve shirt."

My research method is embarrassingly simple but I'll share it so you can use it, too, in future. I started typing "long sleeve" into Google and a lot of advertisements came up for "long sleeve shirts." See my [Google Search Results](https://www.google.com/search?q=long%20sleeve%20shirts&oq=long%20sleeved&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j0l6j69i60.8355j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

Since--for the sake of marketing--ads seek to appeal to public opinion and public good-taste, they use the correct and proper term. For this reason, I conclude that the correct term is "long sleeve shirt."

**EDIT:** This must be one of the words that has more than one correct spelling. In the comments below, Kate Bunting gives me a [Cambridge Dictionary reference](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/long-sleeved) for another spelling: long-sleeved.

The word is defined as being an adjective to mean "having long sleeves:
a long-sleeved T-shirt." Its opposite is given as being "short-sleeved."

Comment: _Long-sleeved_ would also be perfectly acceptable.

Comment: I see you're in the UK. I am not familiar with UK spellings for fashions but I am convinced that the ads get it right; see my edit. The ads I saw apply for North America.

Comment: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/long-sleeved

Comment: Thanks! I added that to my answer.